# FFmpeg settings to convert MTS into MPG for YouTube

Tags: video, youtube, ffmpeg, h.264, libx264

I would like to discuss the optimal parameters for FFmpeg to convert an MTS video file with the following profile for the upload onto YouTube. [YouTube published their suggested resolutions and bitrates settings](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=1728588&guide=1728585&page=guide.cs).

```
// Input video profile
Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 256 kb/s
```

Since [YouTube has length restrictions to the videos](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71673) I also want to cut the original file into pieces.

Here is my current configuration to convert a video. I am running Ubuntu 10.10. with FFmpeg version git-2011-12-31-81980bf.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:15:00 -i input.mts -t 00:30:00 -vcodec libx264 -deinterlace -s hd720 -ab 128k -threads 0 output.mp4
```

I also want to reencode the video since I do not want to upload the large files of the original recording.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to re-encode. Youtube will probably accept the resulting file. You can use FFmpeg to split the video without re-encoding:

`ffmpeg -ss 00:15:00 -i input.mts -t 00:30:00 -c copy output.mkv`

Move `-ss` as an output option (after `-i input.mts`) if the offset is inaccurate or doesn't look right. It is more accurate as an output option, because it will decode everything until the given time, but is much slower than `-ss` as an input option which attempts to immediately seek to the given time. Users of older FFmpeg may have to use `-vcodec copy -acodec copy` instead of `-c copy`.

Comment: It looks like [YouTube does not support the file format](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=1728586&guide=1728585&page=guide.cs). What is the difference between `mts` and `mkv`?

Comment: Just because it's not on their list doesn't mean that they don't accept it. Try it. Works for me, but results may vary. Test a small sample first. MTS and MKV are two different media container formats. See (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats)

Comment: In case I want to reencode the file to minimize the upload size what would be the best parameters?

Comment: The my answer at this question: [FFmpeg sensible defaults](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9057521/1109017)